# Directions and distance from within bounds and outside bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to create a WordPress plugin, that will use the Google maps directions in combination with bounds.

This is an application for km based charge, that has low cost/km into the bounds and high cost/km outside the bounds.

So the question is:

1. Is there a way to know what is the distance from within the bounds point to the bounds border
2. Is there a way to know what is the distance from a point outside the bounds to the bounds borders?

Note that the bounds area will be made with poligons. I have find the way to check if a point in the poligon or outside the poligon.

The problem is what I describe above in the list.

Comment: What is the downvote reason ? Can you help me please to get understaint why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a function in the API that measures distances between LatLngs.

It's called : computeLength() in the geometry library.

Please read this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Distance and Area Functions

The distance between two points is the length of the shortest path between them. This shortest path is called a geodesic. On a sphere all geodesics are segments of a great circle. To compute this distance, call computeDistanceBetween(), passing it two LatLng objects.

You may instead use computeLength() to calculate the length of a given path if you have several locations.

Distance results are expressed in meters.

To compute the area (in square meters) of a polygonal area, call computeArea(), passing the array of LatLng objects defining a closed loop.